# How would a country or kingdom instill loyalty and patriotism in its citizens and military?

Tags: government, military, population, governance, kingdom

How would a country or kingdom instill loyalty and patriotism in its citizens and military? With technology around 1930-1940

Comment: [This](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=nazi+germany) might be a useful case study.

Comment: Kingadamthe1st, welcome. Look at how your own country was doing these things in that period. Whichever country it was, and whatever they were doing, I guarantee you that the population of the time did not see it as evil. Why would our opinion count for more if we weren't even alive at that time?

Comment: Which citizens?  What sort of loyalty and patriotism?  What does the government want from them?  Governments do many and various things, differing from one group (such as children) to the next.  If they were encouraging them to brace for war, it would be different from trying to prevent their slipping into totally private lives in peace.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! As you can see, your question is struggling right now --- it's on the brink of brink of being closed for a variety of reasons. Essentially, SE is a Q&A platform that seeks high quality, focused questions that home in on a particular worldbuilding problem rather than open ended discussion questions. You'll need to focus your question by telling us things about the country you're interested in and about the kind of world you're working with. For example, our (Occidental) ideals of loyalty and patriotism largely grew up in the context of (cont)

Comment: (cont) the Catholic worldview. If your topic culture lacks this or has a radically different understanding of reality, then it stands to reason that their foundations for loyalty and patriotism will be quite different. We can give you a much better answer if we know more about the people, the history, the philosophy, etc of the culture you wish to focus on. Also, in Meta we do have a [sand box](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9981/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) where you can post your question to get help working it into shape for publication here on Main.